# Why there is Invalid Default Value for the table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I executed the query below

```
ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `phone` `phone` VARCHAR( 20 ) 
    CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

and result was ...

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'phone'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not allowing it to be null and then setting it to null as a default value.

Answer (score 1):

You've set a default value of NULL for a column that can't be NULL